# use typescript File array in image tag html Angular 2

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I am currently making a web application where I can upload csv data and pictures on the application and display them. Currently I am stuck because I'm not able to show the images I imported. I import images in from my local drive with:

```
<li *ngIf="loadService.getLoads().length > 0">
    <input type="file" (change)="loadService.importPictures(loadService.getLoads(),$event)" 
           name="datafile" size="40"  multiple>
</li>
```

If the csv list is not imported or empty then the second button to load images will not be displayed. The images are then being put in a Load model class which has a field called picture of type File. The method of ImportPictures simply adds the correct picture to the corresponding load.

I want to be able to use this File in an image html tag but I can't seem to get it to work? Is there a way to do this?

I tried something like this:

```
 <img *ngIf="load.picture" 
      name="recipient" 
      [(ngModel)]="load.picture" 
      src="{{load.picture}}" 
      ngDefaultControl/>
```

Comment: Do you upload the images before trying to use them? Is there any error messages? Is the file paths correct?

Comment: I have the images on my computer and I add them by pressing a button which directs me to a folder on my computer. Then I choose the images I want to show on my web page and these are put in an array of File (File[]). The array of files then exists of Files with this format: **File {name: "023008.png", lastModified: 1503152676606, lastModifiedDate: Sat Aug 19 2017 16:24:36 GMT+0200 (Romance (zomertijd)), webkitRelativePath: "", size: 445672, …}**. I now want to use these files in my html to show the images.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers will not give you the full path to the files when using a file upload so the only way you will be able to display them is to have them within the same folder as your html file. Then you can do:

```
<img [src]="load.name"/>
```

But this will only work in a strictly controlled environment. To use the files outside of purely development environment you will need to first upload the files somewhere and then display them by binding the src property against the newly created url.

Comment: I dont think I need the full path to my files, because I have the array with the images defined in my Typescript. I simply have to show them in my html. The problem is that I need to add pictures in a dynamic way because the loads keep changing so I can't simply put them in a folder in the project itself. Or am I misunderstanding you? If I try it with [src] then I receive a not found 404: **GET http://localhost:4200/[object%20File] 404 (Not Found)**

Comment: Right, so I agree with you that you cannot keep them them in a certain folder because you need it to be dynamic. However, your HTML need the path to the file, it cannot display the image without knowing the path. And you cannot get the path, the browser will not provide it to you. That's why you upload the images first to some type of storage, and then use the new url to display the images.

Comment: oh I see, didn't take that in account... Do you have a suggestion to use as storage? Thank you btw to make it certain that there is no way in doing it this way.

Comment: In my view, the easiest way to store the images in to post them to your server and serve them from there, just google on your server stack (node, asp etc) and "file upload" for multiple examples. If you want to go more advanced then I am a big fan of Amazon S3. They have a js sdk but I have not tried to use it from an Angular client so I do not know if it works out of the box.

Comment: Allright I will further explore this solution. Thank you very much!